# How to convert comma seperated values in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

I have one string contains numbers and i need to convert it in an array. My string is:

```
["50000001","50000022","50000043","50000106"]
```

And i need to convert it in an array in PHP.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That string pretty much looks like JSON, so you could use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$input = '["50000001","50000022","50000043","50000106"]';
$arr = json_decode( $input );
```

Answer (score 4):

The string looks like valid JSON, so use [**`json_decode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for this:

```
$array = json_decode('["50000001","50000022","50000043","50000106"]');
var_dump($array);

// array(4) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(8) "50000001"
//   [1]=>
//   string(8) "50000022"
//   [2]=>
//   string(8) "50000043"
//   [3]=>
//   string(8) "50000106"
// }
```

If you also need to convert the integers-as-strings to integers, use [**`intval`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) and [**`array_map`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$array = array_map("intval", $array);
var_dump($array);

// array(4) {
//   [0]=>
//   int(50000001)
//   [1]=>
//   int(50000022)
//   [2]=>
//   int(50000043)
//   [3]=>
//   int(50000106)
// }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$str = '["50000001","50000022","50000043","50000106"]';

$arr = json_decode($str, true);

var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use json_decode:

```
$array = json_decode('["50000001","50000022","50000043","50000106"]');
```

Simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like JSON, so you can use json_decode(), or you can look up to the explode function. A little more search effort would have brought you there.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

None the less,

```
$string = " ["50000001","50000022","50000043","50000106"]";
explode(",", $string);
//or
json_decode($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string = '["50000001","50000022","50000043","50000106"]';
var_dump(explode(",", trim($string, "[]")));
```

If you do not need the quotes, you can also use this:

```
$string = '["50000001","50000022","50000043","50000106"]';
$array = str_replace('"', '', explode(",", trim($string, "[]")));
var_dump($array);
```